# In C++, using ADO.NET, (MSVS 2013) how do I use a StoredProcedure and then reference the (presumeably) resultant DataTable?

Tags: c++, datatable, ado.net

I'm new to ADO.NET! So, my apologies up front--if you're someone who has no patience with newbies, please move on to the next question.

I have found a great deal of information about the class DataTable, but very little to-the-point, usage examples of HOW to use it.  This article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30490/How-to-Manually-Create-a-Typed-DataTable) tells how to get to the data in the DataTable structure (I think) once I get the data into the DataTable.  I have learned about the steps of Opening, Connecting (though, these words seem to be used almost interchangeably) and, of course, Closing when I'm through.  I'm really looking for the starting steps.

The closest I came to a real example was here:  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/ado/article.php/c6729/Using-ADO-from-C.htm which, I think is quite old.  It uses quite a few C++ calls that are no longer preferred (like cout & sprint), so I'm not sure how relevant it is.

Do I need a whole class just dedicated to interfacing with DataTable?

Does it have to do ALL of my ADO.NET communications?  (I have inherited a project that already did some ADO.NET interfacing in a very tedious & cumbersome way.  It did not use Stored Procedures, which is what I've been asked to do. I'm beginning to wonder if tedious & cumbersome is of necessity--if there's no other way!

What are the necessary imports/using statements necessary to the interface?

Is there a good book for C++ & ADO.NET?  (There are a lot with C# & ADO.NET, although "good" is another question.)

Thank you in advance,
Vauna

Comment: you are talking about MANAGED c++? ever thought about switching to c#? reading the results of a stored procedure into a datatable is easily done with just a few lines of code there ... if you omit error handling and stuff like that ...

Comment: Yes, @PrfctByDsgn, it is managed C++.  And C# is the long-term solution.  In the meantime, I have inherited thousands of lines of C++ code. We are hoping to expand its functionality, a little, while porting it to C# in background.  If I can figure out how to make the current implementation talk to the database using Stored Procedures (which I think involves the class DataTable) it would make the transition much easier.

Comment: Never mind--we blew off ADO.NET, in this particular instance.  Oh, well.  Maybe next time...